# create entry in child table only if the foreign key from the child table has a value assigned to it in parent table

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys, create-table

I have these two tables:

```
create table employeetasks (
    employeeid int not null,
    projectid int not null,
    taskcode char(1),
    primary key (employee, projectid)
);

create table workinghoursperday (
    employeeid int not null,
    projectid int not null,
    date date not null,
    hours float,
    primary key (employeeid, projectid, date),
    foreign key (employeeid) references employeetasks(employeeid),
    foreign key (projectid) references employeetasks(projectid)
);
```

In the second table (child table called workinghoursperday) I want to list how many hours each employee works every day on a specific project, but in order to register the hours the employee worked on that given day on that project the employeeid must have a taskcode assigned to them in the parent table (employeetasks).

For example in the parent table (employeetasks) we can have two entries:

```
FIRST ENTRY:      employeeid | projectid | taskcode
                       1     |     1     |   'A'


SECOND ENTRY:     employeeid | projectid | taskcode
                       2     |     1     |   null
```

Let's say I want to create these two entries in the child table (workinghoursperday):

```
FIRST ENTRY:       employeeid | projectid |     date     | hours
                        1     |     1     | '2020-04-09' | 6.5


SECOND ENTRY:      employeeid | projectid |     date     | hours
                        2     |     1     | '2020-04-10' | 7.5
```

I want the first entry in the child table to be successfull since employeeid 1 has a taskcode ('A' in this case) assigned to it on projectid 1, but the second entry in the child table should fail since employeeid 2 doesn't have a taskcode assigned to it (since the value is null) on projectid 1.

I have no idea how to do this. Any help is greately appreciated!

Comment: Make `taskcode NOT NULL` and use `FK (employeeid, projectid)`

Comment: Thanks for answering, the thing is taskcode cannot be not null since there are cases where it has to be null. I already have employeeid and projectid as foreign keys in my child table.

Comment: you have *two separate* `FKs`, not the same as one `(employeeid, projectid)`

Comment: also, that `NULL` likely means that you are useing `employeetask` table for two different meaning (predicates), likely to result in logical errors.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know that if you combine the keys they will have a different result. Do you mean that I should include the column taskcode in my workinghoursperday table or just reference it without making it a column in the child table? I need to be able to have the possibility to leave taskcode blank in the employeetask, so I don't know how else to do that if not with null

Comment: will post a longer answer

Comment: Perhaps use `INSERT IGNORE` or `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE..`

Answer (score 0):

Started with existence predicates in order to create a "whole" logical story (model). Choose sections of this to adjust your example.

```
-- Employee EMP exists.
--
employee {EMP}
      PK {EMP}

-- Project PRO exists.
--
project {PRO}
     PK {PRO}

-- Task TSK exists.
--
task {TSK}
  PK {TSK}
```

```
-- Project PRO contains task TSK.
--
project_task {PRO, TSK}
          PK {PRO, TSK}

FK1 {PRO} REFERENCES project {PRO}
FK2 {TSK} REFERENCES task    {TSK}
```

```
-- Employee EMP is allocated to project PRO.
--
employee_project {EMP, PRO}
              PK {EMP, PRO}

FK1 {EMP} REFERENCES employee {EMP}
FK2 {PRO} REFERENCES project  {PRO}
```

```
-- Employee EMP is assigned task TSK of project PRO.
--
employee_task {EMP, PRO, TSK}
           PK {EMP, PRO, TSK}

FK1 {EMP, PRO} REFERENCES employee_project {EMP, PRO}
FK2 {PRO, TSK} REFERENCES project_task     {PRO, TSK}
```

Track daily hours by employee project task.

```
-- On date DTE, employee EMP worked HRS hours
-- on task TSK of project PRO.
--
task_hours_day {EMP, PRO, TSK, DTE, HRS}
            PK {EMP, PRO, TSK, DTE}

           FK {EMP, PRO, TSK} REFERENCES
employee_task {EMP, PRO, TSK}
```

For daily employee project hours, create a view.

```sql
-- On date DTE, employee EMP worked HRS_PRO hours
-- on project PRO.
--
-- {EMP, PRO, DTE} -- logical KEY
--
CREATE VIEW project_hours_day
AS
SELECT EMP, PRO, DTE, sum(HRS) AS HRS_PRO
FROM task_hours_day
GROUP BY EMP, PRO, DTE ;
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```

Comment: thank you so much, you have been of great help! really appreciate you sharing your broad mysql knowledge with a noob like me!